# Non-adjacent spill or Multi-conditional lookup using multi-column spill range as lookup key & another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where the department is at the top (H43), and I'm using a Sort, Unique, & Filter nested formula to pull 3 columns from a named table. The filter looks at that department and gives all the IDs, the employee names, and title. The additional column I need is also in that table, but not in an adjacent column, Status. The columns #'s of the columns I need at 7,8,9,5 in that order.

I would like to minimize maintenance of dragging formulas so I'm hoping for one of 2 things: That I can use the spill formula to pull the additional non-adjacent column, or to have a multi-conditional lookup (because here's duplicate IDs) to bring in the Employment status and have it auto-fill from the spill.

The _Pop headers are, currently I'm pulling the last 3, but want employee status. The last 3 columns are extracting data from the first set of columns, but the status is fine as is, so i'd like to not move it, or duplicate it unnecessarily.

| Department | Employee | ID(Name) | Office | Employee Status | FTE | EmployeeID | Name | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Formulas I've tried:

Spills:

This formula pulls the last 3 columns fine, but not the additional status column

`=SORT(   UNIQUE(   FILTER( _Pop[[EmployeeID]:[Title]], _Pop[department]='Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43)),2,1)`

This formula gave odd behavior

`=SORT(   UNIQUE(   FILTER( _Pop, _Pop[department]='Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43),{7,8,9,5}),2,1)`

This attempt gave a #Value! error.

`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(INDEX(_Pop, , {7,8,9,5}), _Pop[department]='Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43)),2,1)`
`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(INDEX(_Pop[#Data], , {7,8,9,5}), _Pop[department]='Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43)),2,1)`

This gave the columns, but not in the order I need:

`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(FILTER(_Pop, _Pop[department]='Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43), (COLUMN(_Pop)=COLUMN(INDEX(_Pop,,7)))+(COLUMN(_Pop)=COLUMN(INDEX(_Pop,,8)))+(COLUMN(_Pop)=COLUMN(INDEX(_Pop,,9)))+(COLUMN(_Pop)=COLUMN(INDEX(_Pop,,5)))),FALSE,FALSE),3,1,FALSE)`

Created helpers in A1:D1 in case it didn't like the constants. no luck

`=INDEX(_Pop,MATCH('Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43,_Pop[department],0),MATCH(COLUMN(A1:D1),COLUMN(INDEX(_Pop,,{7,8,9,5})),0))`

Lookups:

`=XLOOKUP(INDEX(I44#,,1), MATCH(TRUE,($H$43=_Pop[department])*(INDEX(I44#,,1)=_Pop[EmployeeID]),0),_Pop[Employee Status],0,0)`

Comment: `=Filter(choosecols(table,7,8,9,5),condition)` ?

Comment: WIth the sort & unique added: `=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(_Pop,7,8,9,5),_Pop[Department]=$H$43)),2)`

Comment: @kevin would you mind adding this as an answer? This was a much cleaner solution than the one I was able to find and want to make sure the best version is selected. Thank you!

Comment: I definitely stole it from @P.b! I probably wouldn't have understood the question without their comment so I'll let them post the answer

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented you could use: `=FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(_Pop,7,8,9,5),_Pop[Department]=$H$43)`

Or adding SORT and UNIQUE (like Kevin commented): `=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(_Pop,7,8,9,5),_Pop[Department]=$H$43)),2)` (where `2` is the index column of the CHOOSECOLS result)

Comment: Thanks, this was much cleaner than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I ended up looking for was to use a CHOOSE function.

`=SORT(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4}, FILTER(INDEX(_Pop,,7), _Pop[department]='Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43), FILTER(INDEX(_Pop,,8), _Pop[department]='Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43),FILTER(INDEX(_Pop,,9), _Pop[department]='Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43), FILTER(INDEX(_Pop,,5), _Pop[department]='Annualized Hours (2)'!$H$43)),2,1)`